# to launch the application when the sms service recieves sms

Tags: android, service, gps, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to launch an application when a background sms service receives a particular senders sms.I have written the msg receiving part but my app does not start when the msg receives.it needs to start the map location activity.

My msgrecieve class

```
public class MsgRecieve extends Service {
public class MsgReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
try {
        if (bundle != null) {
        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
        log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                        // Show Alert
        if (senderNum.equals("956xxxxxxx")) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
toast.show()
/*Intent  i1 = new Intent(context,MapsActivity.class);
  i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(i1);*/
                     }
                 } // end for loop
             } // bundle is null
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
 }
```

My activity class

```
try {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setApplicationContext();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent intent1 =new Intent(this,MsgRecieve.class);
startService(intent1);
TextView txtImei1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imei1);
TextView txtImei2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imei2);
TextView txtSerial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serialNo);
TextView txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alertMsg);
IMEIHelper imeiHelper = new IMEIHelper();
TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = imeiHelper.getInfo(getApplicationContext());
  if (telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready()) {
      txtImei1.setText(StringHelper.IMEI + "1:" + telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1());
      } else {
              txtImei1.setText(StringHelper.IMEI + ":NA");
             }
            if (telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready()) {
                txtImei2.setText(StringHelper.IMEI + "2:" + telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2());
               }
```

Manifest

```
<service
android:name="edu.am.edu.am.iotm.android.activity.MsgRecieve"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" >
</service>
</application>
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<!--The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to useGoogle Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<intent-filter android:priority="901" >
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: upload your code......

Comment: plese provide pease of code

Comment: register a reciver, and start your activity from onRecive()

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: how can i register it tanku for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [Tutorial For Intercepting SMS](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87):

Manifest:

> ```
> <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms">   
>   <intent-filter>
>       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
>   </intent-filter>
> </receiver>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
>    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
> ```

Broadcast Receiver class:

> ```
> public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
>     
>     // Get the object of SmsManager
>     final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();  
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
>         // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
>         final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();    
>         try {
>             
>             if (bundle != null) {
>                 
>                 final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
>                 
>                 for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
>                     
>                     SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
>                     String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
>                     
>                     String senderNum = phoneNumber;
>                     String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
>
>                     Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
>                     
>
>                    // Show Alert
>                     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
>                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
>                                  "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
>                     toast.show();
>                     
>                 } // end for loop
>               } // bundle is null
>     
>     
>     /* Start a new application*/
>           Intent i;
>           PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
>           try { 
>               i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("application package name");
>               if (i == null)
>                   throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
>               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
>               startActivity(i);
>           } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {  } 
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
>             
>         }
>     }    
> }
> ```

**Edit:**
try this, i have made the edit in you `messagereceive class`:

```
public class MsgRecieve extends Service {
public class MsgReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
try {
        if (bundle != null) {
        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
        log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                        // Show Alert
        if (senderNum.equals("956xxxxxxx")) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
        toast.show()
        Intent mIntent;
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        try { 
            mIntent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.application.package.name");
            if (mIntent == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {  } 
        }
        } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you explain what package manager? i have an application for map locating and now i have to add msg recieving programme in that application.

Comment: put the package name here `manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.youapplication");`   [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)
   and  
[More Information About PackageManager](http://java.dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager)

Comment: i have edited my code, and whats wrong with the code you have in your `msgrecieve` which you have commented for starting a new activity ?

Comment: is there any problem in the main activity regarding the function call??